# Adding google analytics to tizen

Tags: google-analytics, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am trying to add google analytic to tizen web-app with the help of this link

https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/7e2b7fa90012098b?forumID=abebd8c49fee8b80

But when I am running my app its throwing error-

> FileSystem not defined in stats.js

Comment: The link in this question is dead and the question has very little substance without it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Tizen is running on the local filesystem with the URL taking the form `file:///`, so doesn't use `http` or `https`, which Google Tag Manager won't allow.

To work around this, remove the existing Google Tag Manager script from the  tag and use the below code snippet for Google Tag Manager specifically, but this can be similarly done for Google Analytics.

```
<body>
<noscript>
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-xxxxxx"
        height=0 width=0 style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
<script type=text/javascript
    src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-xxxxxx"></script>
<script type=text/javascript
    src=https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js></script>
```

Secondly, you need to configure the Google Analytics Tag. Because GA places some restrictions on the web brower:

```
-The host making the requests to GA needs to use either `http` or `https` as the protocol.
-The host must support storing the Client ID in browser cookies.
-The host must be able to pass a proper Document Location value (the URL) to Google Analytics.
```

For more information, please read this blog article from an expert Google Developer

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/run-google-tag-manager-google-analytics-local-files/

Answer (score 2):

As you use the example of SamsungDForum, it is better to forward this in that forum. 
I found another example there for google analytics, it may be help you.. 
https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/3ad8bd6023af18a7?forumID=1195f8970c4eea64

Comment: this is a dead link :(